# NoClassDefFoundError for junits during mvn test

Tags: java, maven, gson

I have the below two dependencies in my current setup.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.aem</groupId>
    <artifactId>aem-sdk-api</artifactId>
    <version>${aem.sdk.api}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tinify</groupId>
    <artifactId>tinify</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I have this test class which uses the gson dependency from `com.adobe.aem` package, at least that is what the IDE says

[image: Test class]

When I run tests from the IDE or do a `mvn clean install`, all the tests execute fine.

---

I have no use for the `com.tinify` package now and I remove this dependency from the pom.xml.
Running the tests from IDE (right click and execute test) works fine but when I do a `mvn clean install` or `mvn test`, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the `gson` library.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap
    at com.......
```

Running `mvn dependency:tree` with the `com.tinify` package gives me this

```
[INFO] +- com.tinify:tinify:jar:1.6.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.10.0:provided
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.14.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:provided
```

From this I understand, mvn uses the gson library from the `com.tinify` package and removing it is causing this exception. But the `com.adobe.aem` dependency also contains the `gson` package.

How do I get mvn to use the gson library from `com.adobe.aem` package ?

Comment: The scope of the dependencies are differently configured.

Comment: Probably, Tinify has it's GSON dependency scope set to transitive and Adobe has set GSON to provided. For good measure, you should consider providing the GSON dependency yourself.

Comment: Apparently `aem-sdk-api` is a JAR with dependencies. Not sure if that is the cause for this specific problem, but you will for sure have more _fun_ due to this in the future. Might be good to clarify why Adobe distributes this as JAR with dependencies on Maven because that defeats the purpose of using Maven as tool for dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding into the core/pom.xml file the following dependency, the scope will make available the classes that the unit test needs

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Sources
[Unable to create a gson object in a test class in AEM 6.4](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/unable-to-create-a-gson-object-in-a-test-class-in-aem-6-4/m-p/272100)
and [Maven repo for the gson library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)
Hope this helps